# Bash Script help- Text Parsing & Output

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I am having text file of the following type,

```
a  b   c               d
-- -- --              --
1  ok device issue   Some Action which 
                     has to be taken which 
                     is split into many lines
                     under d.
```

I have tried using grep for "issue" however only the first line of 'd' gets printed. The output I got is:

```
1  ok device issue   Some Action which
```

However I want the complete output in d. When I tried saving the file in csv it showed the second line of column d as a new line.

Edit:

The output is obtained from multiple device which stored in a variable from which I am grepping for the one's which are having issues.

Comment: That's happening because what's under `d` is multiple lines. `grep` is working in the way that it's designed. `awk` will do the same thing if you use it to search for `issue` and then print. Your only option is to make `d` one line.

Comment: what Nasir Riley said, except that you can use `awk` in a way to match the whole column if you reassign Record Separator and Field Separator.

Comment: @Ramana can you attach the actual text file?

Comment: `grep -E 'issue|^ `, or use `perl`.

Comment: GNU awk can do fixed-width processing with the FIELDWIDTHS variable. Check the manual

Comment: You mention a CSV file. Could you show it please?

Comment: @Kusalananda Image from csv is attached.

Comment: @computronium  I have attached a snippet from csv. Hope this give a better clarity.

Comment: Though you have your data stored in a file that you consider CSV, it appears all of the data is in the first column of the CSV and your **data** isn't actually CSV at all and so any talk of a CSV in your question is irrelevant and a red herring. Is your **data** (not the file that you store your data in the first column of) fixed width fields or tab separated or what? For your example - you want to find a block that matches a regexp so don't **only** show that one block or we have nothing useful to test a potential solution with. Show, say, 3 blocks where they don't all match the regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` is acting like it should in default mode. From its `man` page:

> ...grep searches for PATTERNS in each FILE.  PATTERNS is one or more
> patterns separated by newline characters, and grep prints each line
> that matches a pattern...

So, it's supposed to turn up **lines** in the text matching a `regex`. Lines are demarcated by the `newline` control code, which explains the behavior you are seeing.
Other than using the `-z` option mentioned in the responses. Assuming "issue" is the regex you want to match (replace with `'Device Degraded'` or `'\sDegraded'` or `'\sError'` if that's what you are actually looking to match); and that the "Corrective Action" column is machine generated and consistent, i.e., always spanning 4 lines you could also simply just run `grep -A 3 '\sissue' > issues` to save **only the lines you are interested in** into a file. You must be able to generate output which looks like:

```
1  ok device issue  Some Action which 
                        has to be taken which 
                        is split into many lines 
                        under d.
--
10  ok device issue Some Action which
            has to be taken which 
            is split into may lines
            under d. 
--
211 ok device issue Some Action which
            has to be taken which 
            is split into many lines 
            under d.
```

check grep's man page to find out more about what these options do.

Answer (score 1):

You need multi line grepping here. For which we will need the PCRE enabled `-P`
option. Since grep will output Null delimited records in the slurp `-z` mode we remove those via tr command.

```
$ < file grep -Pzo '.*\S.*issue.*\n(?:\h+.*\n)+'  | tr -d '\0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a "record" in the input file is exactly as provided by the OP:

```
$ sed '/issue/!d; :a; n; /^[0-9]\{1,\} /d; $!ba' file
1  ok device issue   Some Action which 
                     has to be taken which 
                     is split into many lines
                     under d.
$
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want, using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^[0-9]/ { prt() }
{ rec = rec $0 ORS }
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    if ( rec ~ regexp ) {
        printf "%s", rec
    }
    rec = ""
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v regexp='issue' -f tst.awk file
1  ok device issue   Some Action which
                     has to be taken which
                     is split into many lines
                     under d.
```